# TypeError Exception: argument must be int or float on a view argument inside a template

Tags: django

I'm trying to check if there are any products on the productList, but this shows up:

Exception Value: argument must be int or float - on this line {% for p in productList %} in home.html

If you need extra information let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product

def home(request):
    context = {'productList': Product.objects.all() }
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

home.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Logo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/main.css' %}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainWrapper">
  <header> 
    <div id="logo"> <!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="Logo"> --> 
      LogoName </div>
    <div id="headerLinks">
      <a href="#" title="Login/Register">Login/Registo</a>
      <a href="#" title="Cart">Carrinho de Compras</a></div>
  </header>
  <nav> <a href="1/">1</a> <a href="2/">2</a> <a href="3/">3</a><a href="4/">4</a> <a href="5/">5</a> <a href="6/">6</a> <a href="7/">7</a></nav>
  <section id="offer">
    <h2>Something</h2>
    <p>Something Something</p>
  </section>
<div id="content">
    <section class="sidebar"> 
      <input type="text"  id="search" value="search">
      <div id="menubar">
        <nav class="menu">
          <h2> 1 </h2>
          <hr>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Link">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Link">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Link">Link 3</a></li>
            <li class="notimp"><a href="#"  title="Link">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="menu">
          <h2> 2 </h2>
          <hr>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Link">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Link">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Link">Link 3</a></li>
            <li class="notimp"><a href="#" title="Link">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mainContent">
      {% for p in productList %}

      {% endfor %}
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer> 
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam varius sem neque. Integer ornare.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam varius sem neque. Integer ornare.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footerlinks">
      <p><a href="#" title="Link">Link 1 </a></p>
      <p><a href="#" title="Link">Link 2</a></p>
      <p><a href="#" title="Link">Link 3</a></p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Error Log

http://dpaste.com/1HW39KS

Comment: can you post full error log

Comment: From the error log, the error is triggered by that line in the template, but tracing it through, `Product.objects.all()` is causing an sqlite3 error when calling create_decimal.  I suspect you have a bad price in your data.  Maybe null?  Either start with a new, clean database file or try allowing null on price.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkBailey !
One of the prices had a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers and suggestions! @MarkBailey pointed that the error was due to a database filling error and that was the case. I had a comma instead of a decimal point in one of the price fields.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
{% with i=forloop.counter %}
       {{i|add:"-1"}}
{% endwith %}
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

hope it helps

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion , but  the error is still on the if condition line. thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your `set` tag is setting the value as a `string`. so `i` now is a string, that's why you can't use `divisibleby` tag.

```
{% if productList %}
    {% for p in productList %}
       {% with i=forloop.counter % }
           {% if i|add:"-1"|divisibleby:4 %}
               {# do whatever here #}
           {% endif %}
           {{ p.price }}
           {{ p.name }}
       {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the error is still on the if condition line.

Comment: try `{% if i|add:"-1"|divisibleby:4 %}`

Comment: I've already tried to do that. I don't think the problem is in this line, because if I remove the if condition the same error is presented on the for loop.

Comment: if you can add rest of the template, that will be helpful.. there is some function/tag in which you are sending a string instead of a int of float

Comment: I've added the template to the post now

Comment: Some of references to `i` won't work because they are not within the `with` tag. You need to include all the `{%if i ... ` under the same `with` block.

Comment: But that is not the issue, I've removed the lines inside the for loop and the problem is still there. The list is the problem